# Shorten URL with mod rewrite

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

im trying to shorten my URL's using mod rewrite.

I would like to shorten urls from `/class/hello.php` and instead just use `/hello.php`

In my .htaccess im currently trying to use

```
RewriteEngine on
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteBase /website
RewriteRule ^/.+[.]php$ class/$1.php [L]
```

which does not seem to be working

Comment: Your htaccess is in `website` folder ? In which folder is `class` folder ? Please provide a tree

Comment: yes class and .htaccess are both in my website folder

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something because I don't know `mod-rewrite` but that regex look completely off. Does the first `$` refer to end of line or some type of variable reference?

Comment: @skamazin You should probably read up about both `mod-rewrite` and regex...

Comment: @skamazin yes $ refers to end of the line

Comment: @arco444 I know (a decent amount of) regex, but it's not all standardized. So what is the `<space>class` doing after the `$`. It seems like an impossible match to me (so clearly I'm missing something here).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code in `/website/.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine on
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteBase /website/

RewriteCond $1 !^index\.php$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^((?!class/)[^/]+?\.php)$ class/$1 [NC,L]
```

Comment: this doesnt seem to be working for me. if the regex matches /hello.php, doesnt this mean we should use class$1 without the /, otherwise we will have a double forward slash when the matched regex is substituted in? regardless, this is giving me a internal server error

Comment: That's not correct as there is no leading slash in .htaccess. If URL is `http://domain.com/website/abc.php` then `$1` will be `abc.php` and it will be rewritten to `http://domain.com/website/class/abc.php`. Make sure your `http://domain.com/website/class/abc.php` works.

Comment: http://localhost/website/class/create.php seems to work fine. for some reason the regex's supplied arent working for me?

Comment: i am getting an internal server error, with this message in my apache error logs "AH00124: Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace."

Comment: That means you have some other rules also in `/website/` folder. If that is true then post full ``/website/.htaccess` in question.

Comment: i am using only the code provided by yourself above inside my .htaccess

Comment: When you get 500 error what is exact URL shown in browser? Also what is location of this .htaccess?

Comment: so if i try load http://localhost/website/create.php OR http://localhost/website/class/create.php i get the 500 error. the location of my .htaccess is C:\xampp\htdocs\website\.htaccess

Comment: This rule will internally rewrite in a loop: `class/class/class/class/class/xxx.php`

Comment: @JustinIurman: Thanks that was it, I forgot there was no .htaccess in `class` folder. Dom: Try updated code.

Comment: ok another problem has arisen. now when i go to http://localhost/website (where index.php is located), my home page is not loaded and i get a 404 error

Comment: i am not trying to rewrite my index.php. i would still like index.php to be loaded when i visit localhost/website/, which is the case without the rewrite rule. index.php is located in website, not inside of the class folder

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59752/discussion-between-dom-shahbazi-and-anubhava).

Answer (score 0):

You need to actually capture the part of the regular expression with parentheses to be interpolated in place of the the `$1` variable.

```
RewriteRule ^/(.+)[.]php$ class/$1.php [L]
```

Comment: hm im now using

    RewriteEngine on
    Options +FollowSymlinks
    RewriteBase /website
    RewriteRule ^/(.+)[.]php$ /class/$1.php [L]

which still wont work!